# iterate over an ArrayList containing JSONObjects mule

Tags: arraylist, foreach, mule, mule-studio

I have a flow variable containing a payload of ArrayList of JSONObjects

```
[{{"SeatFrom":"11","SeatThru":"12","InHandDate":"3/25/15","Quantity":"2"}, {{"SeatFrom":"10","SeatThru":"10","InHandDate":"3/20/15","Quantity":"1"},.....]
```

I have set this as payload and iterating over the arraylist in batch of 2

```
<set-payload value="#[flowVars['toUpdate']]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <foreach collection="#[message.payload]" batchSize="2" doc:name="For Each">
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> </for-each>
```

But instead the logger is printing out the object details not the content. I even tried to do a toString() on the payload, but it did not work. How should I correct my code?

Comment: Could you add the stack trace of the error you are getting? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a json-to-object-transformer after setting the payload.

Comment: It does not work, The expression does not evaluate to a type that can be split: org.mule.module.json.JsonData. I actually have a java component downstream which uses this payload from the for-each block.

Answer (score 2):

I would set the returnClass to java.util.HashMap[] to return an array of HashMaps if you are expecting a json array:

```
<flow name="jsontest">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <set-payload value="[{&quot;prop&quot; : &quot;value&quot;},{&quot;prop&quot; : &quot;value&quot;}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </poll>

        <json:json-to-object-transformer
            returnClass="java.util.HashMap[]" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>

        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <logger level="INFO" message="Prop:  #[payload.prop]" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```